# linux bash variable yields 2 different values depending on scope?

Tags: bash

"$name" yields 2 different values:  ?

```
#!/bin/bash

name=whoami
$name                                 # $name yields {user} being me is "jdl"

date >> /home/$name/crondate.txt      # $name yields "whoami"
```

Would like to have the path using "jdl"?

Comment: why not use $USER and $HOME envars that already are present

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to put jdl in name you should use :

```
name=$(whoami)
```

and if you want to print the value `echo $name`

actually what your code does :

```
name=whoami
$name                                 # replace name to whoami and execute it

date >> /home/$name/crondate.txt      # replace name to whoami and the path is /home/whoami/crondate.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

The value of `name` is `whoami`.

In your first example, it is not `$name` itself that yields `jdl`; that's the *output* of the command `whoami` when it is executed.

If you were to run

```
echo "$name"
```

then you would see the value of the variable itself.